# How to revert and fix the file changes in Git

Tags: git

I am using git, I added some files its showing those files in the modified list. I did git diff on that same file and found some unintentional changes like addition of newline were also there in the file.

To get rid of the unintentional changes I did git checkout --  and just copied only those changes back to the file and before doing git add I again did git diff  on the same file it showed the same git diff status which it had shown when I first did the git diff with all the unintentional changes.

How to get out of this?

Comment: Is the extra newline on the last line of the file, or somewhere in the middle? Some editors add a newline to the end of the file if one was not present before.

Comment: It's coming in the middle at the end of the function definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using an IDE?  It is possible that your editor has settings to clean up whitespace, which can cause messy commits.  Check your editor's options; any that offer this feature should also allow it to be turned off.

To fix with git:

- `git reset` to unstage changes
- `git add -p [file]` to do a *partial* add; skip any hunks that you do not want to commit
- `git commit`
- `git checkout .` to get rid of unstaged changes